# How can I see lastest subView after clicking popover embedded in NavigationView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, popover

When click button, a popoverView  embedded in NavigationView appear.
My code is as follows:

```
  -(IBAction)myStuffPOP:(id)sender
   {
    if(myStuffListViewController ==nil)
    {        
        myStuffListViewController = [[MyStuffListViewController alloc] init]; 
    }
    UINavigationController *navcontroller=[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myStuffListViewController] autorelease];
 // Here we create popover controller.
    mystuffPopoverView =  [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navcontroller] ;
    CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[sender frame] fromView:[sender superview]];

    popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100);
    popoverRect.size.height = 40;

    [mystuffPopoverView presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

    [navcontroller setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

}
```

In NavigationView of PopoverView :

```
1st subView ---> 2nd SubView ---> 3rd Subview
```

If I touch `3rd SubView`, PopoverView disappears.

My Question is :

When I click button again, I wanna to see lastest View - `3rd SubView not 1st SubView.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare `UINavigationController *navcontroller;` in .h file
2. Create only onсe `navcontroller` with your root view controller,
   in viewDidLoad method, for example.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {     
       myStuffListViewController = [[MyStuffListViewController alloc] init]; 
       navcontroller=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myStuffListViewController]; }
   ```
3. Show UIPopoverController with exist navigation stack

   ```
   -(IBAction)myStuffPOP:(id)sender    {
       //Here we create popover controller.
       mystuffPopoverView =  [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navcontroller] ;
       CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[sender frame] fromView:[sender superview]];

       popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100);
       popoverRect.size.height = 40;

       [mystuffPopoverView presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
   animated:YES];
       [navcontroller setNavigationBarHidden:NO]; }
   ```
4. Don't forget to `release` objects

   ```
   - (void)dealloc {   
       [myStuffListViewController release];
       [navcontroller release];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

No need to create `UINavigationController` every time. Save it the same way as `MyStuffListViewController`

```
if ( myNavigationController == nil )
    myNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]     initWithRootViewController:myStuffListViewController] autorelease];
```